# Cart matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating a ecommerce website with python Django. Mean While raised this error " Cart matching query does not exist ". What can I do to solve this error.

views.py

```
class AddToCartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "add_to_cart.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        produc_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        # Old Cart
        if cart_id:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
            prd_in_this_cart = cart_obj.cartitem_set.filter(product=produc_obj)
            # Item already exist in cart
            if prd_in_this_cart.exists():
                cartproduct = prd_in_this_cart.last() # first()
                prd_in_this_cart.quantity += 1
                cartproduct.total += produc_obj.amazon_rate
                cartproduct.save()
                cart_obj.total += produc_obj.amazon_rate
                cart_obj.save()
            # Item already exist in cart
            else:
                cartproduct = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=produc_obj, quantity=1, total=produc_obj.amazon_rate, subtotal=produc_obj.amazon_rate)
                cart_obj.total += produc_obj.amazon_rate
                cart_obj.save()
        # New Cart
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(total=0)
            self.request.session["cart_id"] = cart_obj.id
            cartproduct = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=produc_obj, quantity=1, total=produc_obj.amazon_rate, subtotal=produc_obj.amazon_rate)
            cart_obj.total += produc_obj.amazon_rate
            cart_obj.save()
        return context
```

Comment: `cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)` get throws an exception if there is no matching instance

Comment: I'm cleared my cookies then it is fixed.